# Two foreign Key of same table in one table in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

my team member model :-

```
var teamMember = {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    level: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    supervisorId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: "employees",
            key: "id"
        }
    },
    employeeId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        unique: true,
        references: {
            model: "employees",
            key: "id"
        }
    }
```

and there is employee model

mapping:-

```
db.employee.hasOne(db.teamMember);
db.teamMember.belongsTo(db.employee);
```

my query function

```
        db.teamMember.findOne({
        where: { employeeId: req.employee.id },
        include: [db.employee]

    })
    .then(teamMember => {
        if (!teamMember) {
            throw ('no teamMember found');
        }
       consol.log(teamMember)
    })
```

my **teamMember** table is like=

id------employeeId------supervisorId

2 ----------- 4 ------------- 5

Problem is -: so when i m asking for row in teamMember whose employeeId is 4. that should be include with supervisorId(JOIN) and it returns row with employee included of 4 (id) . i want employee of 5th id .

**Both supervisorId and employeeId are reffer to employee table.**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't need to set the fields of employee and supervisor on the model, just doing the belongTo it will add it, and there you can specify the if is unique and use "as" so you can know with employee are you refering on the join, the regular employee or the supervisor, something like this:

```
db.teamMember.belongsTo(db.employee, {as: 'SupervisorId'});
db.teamMember.belongsTo(db.employee, {as: 'RegularEmployeeId'});
```

and then on your query add the include like this:

```
include: [{
    model: db.employee,
    as: 'SupervisorId
}]
```

Comment: only we need belongsTo for include ? their is no need of hasMany , hasOne ??  by the way your answer works .Thanks

Comment: On your particular case belongTo is enough. Depending on your database schema you will need hasMany, hasOne, etc.

Comment: what about the migration file, will this need to be created?

Comment: Thanks man, in addition to this answer, you can add the key, for example: {as: ''MyOwnName', foreignKey: 'supervisorId'}