# Cant seem to set multiple foreign key references to the same model in sequelize, Node

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a node backend that I am build and I have two models I am building with sequelize. A user model and friend model. I want to have two fields in the friend model (requester, requested) that reference two different users from the user model.

The way I have it set right now in the postgres shell is that there is only 1 reference to the user model that is firends_userId. I want to change that to have two.

here is my code:

models:

```
const seq = require('sequelize');
const { postgres } = require('../../index');
const { user } = require('./User')

const friend = postgres.define(
  "friend",
  {
    id: {
      type: seq.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    blocked: {
      type: seq.BOOLEAN,
      default: false,
      null: false
    },
    favorite: {
      type: seq.BOOLEAN,
      default: false,
      null: false
    },
  },{
    createdAt:  seq.DATE,
    updatedAt:  seq.DATE,
  },
);
postgres.sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("friend table is synced")
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("caught error with friend:  " + error)
  })

user.hasMany(friend, {as: 'friender', foreignkey: 'frienderId'});
user.hasMany(friend, {as: 'friended', foreignkey: 'friendedId'});

module.exports.friend = friend;
```

and

```
const seq = require('sequelize');
const { postgres } = require('../../index');

const user = postgres.define(
  "user",
  {
    id: {
      type: seq.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    username: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      unique: true,
      null: false,
      require: true,
      validate: {
        isAlphanumeric: true,
        allowNull: false,
        len:  [8,16],
      }
    },
    email: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      unique: true,
      null: false,
      require: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
        allowNull: false,
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      null: false,
      require: true,
      validate: {
        allowNull: false,
        len:  [8, 18],
      }
    },
    first_name: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      null: false,
      require: true,
      validate: {
        allowNull: false,
        isAlpha: true,
      }
    },
    last_name: {
      type: seq.STRING,
      null: false,
      require: true,
      validate: {
        allowNull: false,
        isAlpha: true,
      }
    }
  },{
    createdAt:  seq.DATE,
    updatedAt:  seq.DATE,
  },
);
postgres.sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("friend table is synced")
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("caught error with friend:  " + error)
  })

module.exports.user = user;
```

this is the current table in postgres shell

```
splitter=# \d+ friends;
                                                         Table "public.friends"
  Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |               Default               | Storage | Stats target | Description 
----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 id       | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('friends_id_seq'::regclass) | plain   |              | 
 blocked  | boolean                  |           |          |                                     | plain   |              | 
 favorite | boolean                  |           |          |                                     | plain   |              | 
 DATE     | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |                                     | plain   |              | 
 userId   | integer                  |           |          |                                     | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "friends_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "friends_userId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL

splitter=#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to write composite primary keys in Sequelize model by specifying `primaryKey: true` for more than one column but Sequelize doesn't currently support composite primary keys, so there is no way to do it.

See https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/311 (Discussion related to composite foreign keys which is not possible to do in squelize that directly means composite primary keys are not possible too).

For having multiple foreign keys pointing to one table `belongsTo` method can be used.

For more details you can refer to this:

[Two foreign Key of same table in one table in sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523203/two-foreign-key-of-same-table-in-one-table-in-sequelize)

Documentation:

https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/associations/#belongsto

Comment: I meant to say foreign key not primary key

Comment: updated the answer, has given a reference to do that as well.Hope it helps.

Comment: it worked after i looked at the article you linked. thanks